# Userscript code works in Firefox but not in Chrome? (unsafeWindow)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, twitter, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am using this userscript in Firefox that counts unread tweets in Tweetdeck and colors the new tweets.

It works fine with Firefox (Greasemonkey), but in Chrome I'm not getting anything. Here is the code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     TweetDeck Unread Notifications
// @include  https://tweetdeck.twitter.com
// @include  https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
var head, style;
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = ".tdUnreadUnread { background-color: #444444; }";
head.appendChild(style);

function animate_bg(ele, from, to) {
ele.css("background-color", "rgba(68, 68, 68, " + (from += from > to ? -1 :    1) / 10 + ")");
if (from != to) setTimeout(function () {
    animate_bg(ele, from, to)
}, 20);
}

var counter = 0;
var loadingTime = true;

unsafeWindow.tdUnreadRefresh = function () {
var detail = $(".js-detail-content");
$("article").each(function (i) {
    if (detail.length == 0) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("tdUnreadUnread")) {
            $(this).addClass("tdUnreadUnread");
            if (!loadingTime) {
                counter++;
                $(this).mouseenter(function () {
                    counter--;
                    $(this).off("mouseenter");
                    animate_bg($(this), 10, 0);
                });
            } else animate_bg($(this), 10, 0);
        }
    }
});

if (counter > 0) {
    document.title = "(" + counter + ") TweetDeck";
} else {
    document.title = "TweetDeck"
       }
}
  unsafeWindow.tdUnreadLoadingOver = function () {
  loadingTime = false;
  }

  setInterval("tdUnreadRefresh()", 1000);
  setTimeout("tdUnreadLoadingOver()", 30000);
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.
Thanks
Bob

Comment: This has been covered in other questions. But bottom line for your script here, since you are using `@grant none`:  (1) replace all `unsafeWindow.` with `window.`.  (2) Make sure your Chrome users have installed and are using Tampermonkey.  ... Your script requires injection if you try to use pure Chrome -- which is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Brock, it works perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: You're welcome.  It also still works in Firefox, right? ;)

Answer (score -1):

IIRC the object unsafewindow is specific to Mozilla Firefox and isn't supported with Google Chrome.
Instead of using unsafewindow, you might want to export your functions using the exportFunction feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction

Comment: Not true.  Chrome supports unsafeWindow but the behavior is different. Also, neither unsafeWindow nor exporting functions is needed with `@grant none` in effect.